# Python requests: The html of page is not visible in text format

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am trying to access a page and it's html looks like:

```
?2?pɢ???=???I????܉??s????   [??AX#?`s??5???2`?| ,q?ɲ?=h?}VTŬ~?Y?}u3cx?pȢ?K_Ol&ɡ??'N??Y??n5?890??G???&$?%J#?ܩ?ѡ
1?y???
$]    &'ι?\?~T?=??@N?C?$??K? ??iu"T?M
  ?6>?&5?:??sJ???xi???V??N??????3R7u??ǹ??7qs??<*????????@3?
EWu}??'F??Z??߶O?????Fc۰?S???h??/????h???[kS(                        f?\˹?@e???7_~~??*'?Jq??i?͛?J?W?T?Y]S??ӫ?~??k՘H??
w?L??ws??M?h?V?؊<[ ?
??A?G?w?
```

What's that? is it some encoding/decoding thing? how to view the html?

The code is here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json



headers_initial = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    }    
r = requests.get('https://www.example.com/', headers=headers_initial)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            html = r.text.strip()
            print(html)
```

Comment: show your relevant code

Comment: @Argus done.. code added.

Comment: what are the `headers_initial` ?

Comment: status_code is 403 you have to bypass captcha first then you will able to get r.text

Comment: @Derlin had forgot to added. Done now

Comment: @Argus Status code is `200` for me.

Comment: Are you encoding utf-8? This is what the site uses. Find out your encoding with `r.encoding`. If its not utf-8, do: `r.encoding = 'utf-8'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your headers. Just remove the `accept-encoding` and it should work fine.

*edit*: the `accept-encoding` specifies if we can handle compressed data. `requests` doesn't, so if you need to specify the header, use the `identity` property, meaning "just send me the page without compression".

Comment: Oh My God!! but .. the page being accessed via browser did not have such issue

Comment: a browser doesn't have the same capabilities as a small python library :)

Comment: Also, the browser wasn't sending that heading.  Why were you sending it?

Comment: @JohnGordon Chrome was showing `accept-encoding` in headers section

Comment: @JohnGordon Chrome was showing `accept-encoding` in headers section